# Column not found in laravel polymorphic relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, polymorphism

developers :)

I'm made a relationship (many-to-many polymorphic) in laravel

between :

- users
- clothes , shoes , ...ect (each one is a model on it's own )

**hint:** the user can favorite any one he like (clothes or shoes ...etc)

**user model :**

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
public  function  clothes()
    {

        return $this->morphToMany('Etrade\clothes\Clothes' ,'favoritable' )
       ->withTimestamps('created_at','updated_at');

    }
}
```

**clothes model :**

```
class Clothes extends Model
{

 // relationship with user
    public  function  user()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany('Etrade\Users\User' ,'favoritable')
       ->withTimestamps('created_at','updated_at');
    }

}
```

**favoritable model :**

```
class Favriable extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'favoritables';

    public function favoritable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

**fetching the data using relationship :**

*- get all users for given clothes :*

```
$clo= Etrade\clothes\Clothes::find(35);

$clo->user; // fetch the relation

=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#760
     all: [
       Etrade\Users\User {#761
         id: 4,
         name: "Reta Paucek",
         email: "ahegmann@example.org",
         gender: 0,
         mobile: "",
         city_id: 0,
         active: 0,
         friend_status: 1,
         created_at: "2016-12-26 18:53:51",
         updated_at: "2016-12-26 18:53:51",
         pivot: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphPivot {#213
           favoritable_id: 35,
           user_id: 4,
           created_at: "2016-12-30 03:34:58",
           updated_at: "2016-12-30 03:34:58",
         },
       },
     ],
   }
```

**- get all clothes for given user:**

```
 $user = Etrade\Users\User::find(4);

 $user->clothes; // fetch the relationship
```

**Getting error :**

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'favoritables.clothes_id' in 'field list' (SQL: select
`clothes`.*, `favoritables`.`favoritable_id` as `pivot_favoritable_id`, `favoritables`.`clothes_id` as `pivot_clothes_id`, `favoritables`.`created_at` as `pivo
t_created_at`, `favoritables`.`updated_at` as `pivot_updated_at` from `clothes` inner join `favoritables` on `clothes`.`id` = `favoritables`.`clothes_id` where
 `favoritables`.`favoritable_id` = 4 and `favoritables`.`favoritable_type` = Etrade\Users\User)'
```

**My question :** how to fix this error ,,, the relationship work in one direction not for both ??

Comment: Did you find the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking that you copy the code correctly, if yes, then I can see spelling mistake there, sorry but I'm underlevel to use 'comment'.

```
//Favriable, or Favoritable
class Favriable extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'favoritables';

    public function favoritable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

Please note that Laravel's Eloquent use 'snake-case' to define a vocabs or something, check this out:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#defining-models

I can say you must be careful with Laravel's Eloquent when it comes to spelling. She's strict and straight.

Plus, if your table is called "favorites", the model should be "Favorite".
If the table in the database is called "stars", the model should be "Star", just to name few examples.

Hope this enlighten something.